# When running command "python train.py" to train word-rnn, getting "no module named numpy" error.

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, cmd, anaconda

OS: Windows 10
Using anaconda3 - 5.2, running commands in Anaconda command prompt.

Here's the commands I used to locate the word-rnn and activate the conda enviroment, plus the error messages when I attempt to train the model. I am also going off of a Mac based tutorial, so please correct me if "python train.py" is the incorrect command to being training.

(base) C:\Users\mower>conda activate tensorflow

(tensorflow) C:\Users\mower>cd "C:\Users\mower\Downloads\word-rnn-tensorflow-master"

(tensorflow) C:\Users\mower\Downloads\word-rnn-tensorflow-master>python train.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 2, in 
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

(tensorflow) C:\Users\mower\Downloads\word-rnn-tensorflow-master>

Comment: try `pip install numpy`

Comment: `conda install numpy`

Comment: I am a complete newbie at this, now after running "conda install numpy" I get a similar error, but now there is "no tensorflow module". Did I mix up installing anything? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that numpy is not installed in your conda environment.
I suggest like the others in the comments that you install it:

```
conda activate tensorflow
conda install numpy
```

Comment: Ok, tried doing both of these with an update of anaconda. Still getting this :

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Comment: seems to me like the same problem just with the tensorflow module.
just install that, too.

Comment: Worked! Thanks. First TensorFlow program

Comment: Your are welcome :) Could you please mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's `pip` installer or anaconda's own installer to install numpy. In `pip` you use:
`pip install numpy`
OR
you can use anaconda like below:
`conda install numpy`

Answer (score 0):

You can check installed packages in your conda environment using

```
conda list
```

See whether numpy and tensorflow are in this, if not, install with

```
conda install numpy
pip install tensorflow
```